# Straddle position

Tags: stretching, calisthenics, hamstring, glutes

At this moment I am working on my straddle planche.

I've noticed that when performing it I've got those 2 problems:

- I am unable to fully straighten my legs ( lack of hamstring flexibility? )
- while squeezing my glutes I feel some kind of stress (almost as if it were a cramp) in my hips area [only in the straddle position]

I've made some research and I have found that they are most likely problems related to flexibility.

Are there some exercise/some streches for improving my straddle position? (especially for the planche if possible)

Comment: Can you get into the straddle position when lying face-down on the floor? If so, your inability to straighten your legs is probably actually an inability to hold the planche with straight legs, rather than an inability to straighten your legs.

Comment: @DavidScarlett so it could also be a motor / coordination problem?

Comment: I was thinking strength or balance. As you extend your legs, your centre of mass moves down towards your feet which, in a planche, would put greater demands on your shoulders and, if your straddle wasn't wide enough, could also shift your balance back enough that your legs tilt down to touch the ground.

Answer (score 2):

These issues might be related to the each other because your hamstrings and glutes work together in many movements and they are the main muscles (along with quads) that make hip / leg movement possible. So there might be a connection there.

```
I am unable to fully straighten my legs ( lack of hamstring flexibility? )
```

Yes, this seems to be a hamstring flexbility issue. This can solved by consistently doing stretches (best would be on a daily basis). There are many great hamstring stretches that you can do both standing up or laying on your back.

```
while squeezing my glutes I feel some kind of stress in my hips area [only in the straddle position]
```

This also sounds like a mobility-type of issue, try doing some hip openers before you start your planche training to find out if that makes any difference. If it does, you know what the problem is and how to sove it. **For example, the pigeon pose could be helpful to help resolve this issue.**